# In rcov, is there a way to find which test method traversed a given line of code being tested?

Tags: ruby, code-coverage, rcov

In rcov, is there a way to find which test methods were tracked as having covered a given line of code (in your target code that you're testing)?

Comment: Might I ask why this would be interesting to know? Or is it because code seems covered without having any tests for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm pretty sure, that rcov doesn't support this feature.

Since the documentation  for the [CoverageInfo](http://relevance.github.com/rcov/classes/CoverageInfo.html) Class suggests, that rcov only tracks if a given linen was executed, not in what context.